# why is the child div outside of its parent when floating right?

Tags: css

Why is Chrome displaying the login boxes below the parent 'heading'?

I have no problem with iexplorer.

How can I fix this for Chrome?

http://jsfiddle.net/dwLSB/

```
<form action="" class="login">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="uname" /><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="pword" />

    </form>
```

Comment: Can you provide more info? Below what? If you mean when the page is shrunk you'll need to set a min-width on the parent container

Comment: I'm viewing in chrome and I don't have the issue you described.

Comment: The username/password boxes appear outside of the black 'heading' with the green border. I'm using Version 31.0.1650.48 m of Chrome on Windows 7. The window is full size and hasn't been shrunk.